# JQuery - $.ajax POST does not send .data to web server

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, post

I am using the JQuery $.ajax post command to invoke an ajax event on my web server:

```
var formParams = "fe1=y&fe2=m&fe3=m";

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/foo.jsp',
    async: false,
    data: formParams,
    complete: function(xmlRequestObject, successString){
        ymmReceiveAjaxResponse(xmlRequestObject, successString);
    }
});
```

The ajax component successfully calls the web page, but it does not include any of the post data.
ie - `"(HttpServletRequest) request.getParameterMap.size() == 0"` - I'd expect 3, but am getting zero.

Changing the above command from POST to a GET makes everything work just fine.

TIA

Comment: This question has been answered in other threads, as I've just stumbled across the cause of the problem - using FireBug, and opening the opening the Net sniffer do-hicky, I'm seeing that the web server is responding with a status 302 on the call to the web page.  I'll outline my solution to the problem in a bit.

Answer (score 5):

The cause of the problem was found using FireBug and opening the opening the Net gadget.

I'm seeing that the web server is responding with a status 302 on the call to the web page.

Expanding upon the 302 request in Firebug/Net, and examining the Params, Headers, Response, and HTML quickly identified that it was an application specific issue originating on the server.

Thanks for everyone's feedback

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/foo.jsp',
    async: false,
    data: { fe1: "y", fe2: "m", fe3: "m" },
    complete: function(xmlRequestObject, successString){
        ymmReceiveAjaxResponse(xmlRequestObject, successString);
    }
});
```

It should work.

Comment: My mistake is I was trying to access $_POST['data'] .. but if I wanted to do that , I would have to have it like so **data : { data : 'someValue' },** .. thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 1):

Your code *as quoted* is fine (I've tried it locally).

My guess is that the `formParams` string in your question is just an example, and in reality you're doing something to generate that string on the fly, and the problem lies in *that* code instead.

For instance, are you sure you're escaping characters correctly (using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent))? Or better yet, let jQuery deal with it, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/foo.jsp',
    async: false,
    data: {
        fe1: $("#somefield1").val(),
        fe2: $("#somefield2").val(),
        fe3: $("#somefield3").val()
    },
    complete: function(xmlRequestObject, successString){
        ymmReceiveAjaxResponse(xmlRequestObject, successString);
    }
});
```

If you pass in an object, jQuery will handle the URI-encoding for you. If you *really* want to do it yourself:

```
var formParams =
    "fe1=" + encodeURIComponent($("#somefield1").val()) +
    "fe2=" + encodeURIComponent($("#somefield2").val()) +
    "fe3=" + encodeURIComponent($("#somefield3").val());
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/foo.jsp',
    async: false,
    data: formParams,
    complete: function(xmlRequestObject, successString){
        ymmReceiveAjaxResponse(xmlRequestObject, successString);
    }
});
```

There I haven't encoded the field names because those names don't have any special chars in them; you need to if your form names are more interesting than that.

Comment: You're totally right that this is stub code; I'm actually invoking the serialize() method on a form field ie - `var formParams = $("#myForm").serialize();`, and that doesn't seem to do anything for me.

Comment: @Missy: Hmmm, `serialize` will handle the encoding for you, so that's not it. Fundamentally, the code should work, and does work at this end, so you'll have to step through with a debugger and see what jQuery's actually sending. It could be that jQuery's doing its job, but for whatever reason the config routing the request to your JSP is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

After frustratingly trying for four hours, I found out that it is able to achieve this by setting the `contentType` in ajax `POST` as follows,

```
var dataToSend = {
     "username" : $("#username").val(),
     "password" : $("#password").val()
};

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "somepage.jsp",
   data: dataToSend,  
   contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", //this is must
   success: function(datum, msg, textStatus){
        $("#result").html("<h3>" + "Status : " + msg + "</h3>")
        .fadeIn("slow");
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `success`:

```
var formParams = "fe1=y&fe2=m&fe3=m";

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/foo.jsp',
    async: false,
    data: formParams,
    success: function(data) {
       alert('response data = ' + data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Whether he uses `success` or `complete` has no bearing on the data not being sent to the server in the first place. (And he can use `complete` if he wants to, it works just fine. :-) )