# Sending POST data to AJAX without a Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP script that is called by an AJAX call triggered by a link click. Normally, I just use a form and pass all of the form data to my PHP scripts, but I would like to manually send POST data through my AJAX so I can avoid using a form. How can I do this?

My JQuery/AJAX:

```
$(".likes-count a").click(function() {

    var post= $(this).parents(".post-bottom").find('.comment-input').val();
    // this value is from another form, this is the value that I need in my PHP script

    // grabs and updates the comment count
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "myscript.php",  
        data: 'post-id' : post, // This is what I have tried so far
        success: function(html) {
            alert(html);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery - $.ajax POST does not send .data to web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596341/jquery-ajax-post-does-not-send-data-to-web-server)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for this:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "myscript.php",  
    data: {'post-id':post},  //notice curly braces
    success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
    }
});
```

If you want to send multiple parameters you can send them comma separated:

```
data: {'post-id':post,'param2':'param2Value'},
```

Comment: Don't forget to `return false;` after the AJAX call.

Comment: @Deryck Thanks for the note. Yes `return false;` will be needed, but after `ajax`, and before finishing the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({  
   type: "POST",  
   url: "myscript.php",  
   data: {post-id:post,article:nextvalue},
   success: function(html) {
      alert(html);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is just fine,But change this

`data: 'post-id' : post`

to this

`data: {'post-id':post}`

That's it...